# Why doesn't the memory being used by a program change, when more memory allocations are done?

Tags: c, memory

I have the following program:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
  double*a;
  double*b;
  double*c;
  double*d;
  double*e;
  double*f;
  double*g;
  double*h;
  double*i;
  double*j;
  double*k;
  double*l;
  double*m;
  double*n;
  double*o;
  double*p;
  double*q;
  while(1){
    a=malloc(1000000*1000000000000*sizeof(double));
    b=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    c=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    d=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    e=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    f=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    g=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    h=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    i=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    j=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    m=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    n=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    o=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    p=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
    q=malloc(1000000*1000000000000);
  }
}
```

and the task manager issues the following memory usage:

[image]

I, then, changed the program to

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
  double*a;
  while(1){
    a=malloc(1000000*1000000000000*sizeof(double));
  }
}
```

compiled it, and task manager showed:

[image]

Shouldn't memory usage be higher in the first program? What am I missing here?

Comment: Your calls to `malloc` are probably failing (you are requesting an insane amount of memory at every `malloc`). Some OSes have [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment). A typical laptop and OS can have [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))es using a few gigabytes each! Read documentation of [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory), and use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: that was it, thank you!

Comment: Some OS can return a valid pointer on `malloc()` but does not really claim the space until you access it. I once tried to `malloc()` until it returns `NULL`, and it gave me much more memory than was available. Lesson learned: Such benchmarks are not trivial.

Comment: I’d print out the pointers. Good chance they are all null pointers because your computer doesn’t have a million terabytes as backing Store for virtual memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory allocators like the glibc memory allocator have memory limits. This means making huge allocations could end up on a failed allocation. A NULL pointer is returned in such cases.

Check out return value of those mallocs to see what is happening, tho it is obvious that the request is too long to be allocated.